# Thread join() referencing class member

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to create a Sender class that instantiates thread objects that have a certain workflow (`SenderWorkflow`), but I am having an issue with calling the default methods found on the `std::thread` library, specifically the `std::thread::join()` method.

The compiler is complaining about the following error:

```
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
```

How can I call the join function for a specific object of class `Sender`?

```
//sender.h
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Sender {
public:

    static bool isFinished;

    Sender() //sender constructor creates a sender thread object
    {
        std::thread worker(Sender);
    }

    void SenderWorkflow();

    void join() {
        std::thread::join();
    }

};
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "Sender.h"

int main()
{
    Sender mSender; //Create thread object for worker
    Sender::isFinished = true; //
    mSender.join(); //wait for the worker thread to finish execution
}
```

```
//sender.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "Sender.h"

void Sender::SenderWorkflow()
{
    while (!Sender::isFinished)
    {
        std::cout << "Working... \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is just confusing: You are passing a class (`Sender`) to the constructor of a thread instance. That thread instance is going out of scope without joining or being detached. You're trying to join something, without even specifying a thread instance, but rather using a static call to the `thread` class. None of this works or makes sense! Provide a [mcve] instead! BTW: You probably have some tutorial for threads. If it's online, provide the URL and someone will tell you if it is good or bad.

Comment: You have to tell the computer **which** thread you want it to join. Also if you want to use classes you should look up how they work. You don't have to use classes.

Answer (score 1):

`worker` isn't a member of `Sender`, its a local variable. If it was a member you could just do `worker.join()`:

```
class Sender {
public:

    static bool isFinished;
    std::thread worker;
    
    Sender()
    : worker(&Sender::SenderWorkflow, this)
    {
    }

    void SenderWorkflow();

    void join() {
        worker.join();
    }

};
```

Note that your syntax for creating a thread which calls `SenderWorkflow` was incorrect too.

As `isFinished` is used from multiple threads it should be `static std::atomic<bool> isFinished` to help avoid data races.

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot for the effort. I declared ```static std::atomic<bool> isFinished = false;``` as class parameter including the <atomic> library, however the join operation will not work on my example. I tried declaring the variable as global and the same issue persists. I run also on debug mode and it seems that it goes through the ```worker.join();``` but somehow the thread does not stop after that.

Comment: @PolarBear ask a new question with your updated code

Comment: note that `main` probably sets `isFinished = true` before `SenderWorkflow` starts executing

Comment: Thanks a lot Alan! I will ask a new proper question.